# Sql to get the max version group by view, and include other column values

Tags: sql, plsql

[image]

I am trying to select all values in this table, grouping by `view_name` with the highest version

So I want to select rows with `core_id` 1234 and 1236

```
SELECT
  MAX(version),
  view_name
FROM csa_help_admin cha
GROUP BY view_name
```

The above select gets me the rows I want, but since the are aggregated I can't get the `core_id` and `help_active` values

I realize group by is an aggregate function but does anyone have suggestions of how to get the desired result

I am using pl sql by the way

Comment: Doesn't simple MIN() or MAX() work on columns with single value?

Comment: which DBMS oracle ?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul if one says pl/sql he should expect oracle answers

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a specific syntax which is very efficient

```
select
    max(core_id) keep (dense_rank last order by version),
    view_name
from csa_help_admin cha 
group by view_name
```

which means get the max core_id over rows which have the greater version, max is just in case there many rows with same view_name and version.

EDIT with help_active column:

```
select
    max(core_id) keep (dense_rank last order by version),
    max(help_active) keep (dense_rank last order by version),
    view_name
from csa_help_admin cha 
group by view_name
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for thank you, how would I output the help_active column

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to use the statement that you came up with, and join it back to the original table to get everything you need:

```
select * from csa_help_admin cha
inner join (
    select max(version) as version, view_name 
    from csa_help_admin cha 
    group by view_name
) B on cha.version = B.version and cha.view_name = B.view_name
```

Comment: Thanks this also works, just for the oracle syntax the alias for the table is just B, not as B, incase someone uses your answer in future

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise since I haven't been working with Oracle before. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to suffice your need.

```
SELECT CORE_ID,
  VERSION,
  VIEW_NAME,
  HELP_ACTIVE
FROM
  (SELECT CORE_ID,
    VERSION,
    VIEW_NAME,
    HELP_ACTIVE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY VERSION DESC) RN
  FROM CSA_HELP_ADMIN
  )A
WHERE A.RN = 1;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same way as proposed above, you can use temporary query (I don't know if joining a request works in every RDBMS):

```
with tmp_req as (
select max(version) as version, view_name 
    from csa_help_admin cha 
    group by view_name
)
select csa.* from csa_help_admin csa
where
csa.version = tmp_req.version and
csa.view_name = tmp_req.view_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.* 
from (select max(version) version, view_name 
      from csa_help_admin  
      group by view_name) a 
inner join csa_help_admin b 
on a.version =b.version and 
a.view_name = b.view_name
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer rahter than just posting code?